# Gem Install - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, neat

I'm trying to install a few gems, specifically Bourbon and Neat. When trying to install Neat though, it seems to install just fine. But when I run `neat -v` or `neat install`, I get this error.

```
/Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mkdir': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20140920-60083-s3sack

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/json-1.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/json-1.5.5/gem_make.out
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `block in mktmpdir'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:142:in `create'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mktmpdir'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:14:in `build'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/raph/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.3/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
    from /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
    from /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what is happening here. If anyone has a clue, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the log file `/Users/raph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/json-1.5.5/gem_make.out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using a mix of RVM and RBENV to install Ruby and your gems. Most users choose one or the other: the behaviour you are seeing is hard to predict and won't normally be seen.

Comment: Oh really, I think I might be. Is there a way to uninstall both and start all over again using homebrew?